# Visually, how does the screen look when you locally log into a machine running Windows Server Core?

Tags: windows-server-core

With the Server Core option chosen during the installation of Windows Server, I've seen several references to no GUI being present. I'm totally blind and as a result screenshots arn't that useful to me, but just so that I can get an understanding of how this works, when a user logs into a machine with Server Core what do you see? Is there still a Start button, or is the screen blank?

Comment: On server core its like headless meaning, you have an windows where ususally a command prompt is waiting for you to login, its more like a Linux machine or DOS window, from where you can start your activity.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No GUI shell, there is only the console.

[image]

LoginUI.exe is text based. Then you are dropped into a cmd.exe.  Do everything at a PowerShell prompt. There is window management, but no Start menu and no desktop, only a blank black screen. Task Manager is still useful for running new shells and reviewing processes.

I am not qualified to say how good screen readers are in this environment.

Remote management from a desktop is a better experience for everybody. Possibly even more so if you can access full ease of access tools.

Comment: Thanks for this. So - in the case that I wanted to download and use GUI-based tools (a web browser, for example), how would I initially go about downloading the file if a browser isn't pre-installed? My first thought would be to copy the file over to the server, but what other options would work if there's no GUI or similar tools pre-installed?

Comment: A GUI, including a browser, is not possible with Windows Server Core or Nano, it is all PowerShell. You can still install Server with desktop experience if that is more comfortable. Possibly you can reliably deploy Core with remote management enabled, so you always can get a remote PowerShell session from a desktop.

Answer (score 1):

If you use remote desktop it is really close to a basic xserver session with an xterm (if you know linux). 
With remote desktop you see a black background and 1 or 2 cmd windows (it depends on the win server version). If 2, the second one runs an helper script named sconfig and used to speed up standard activities: set an IP, check updates...
Still you can download and install and use gui tools like firefox.

Entering via powershell it is like any other windows where powershell Enter-PSsession is enabled: just your ps window (a la ssh if you know linux)